# How can I merge two json objects in same array by Id in another array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework, angular

I have a a big json array and have many objects and arrays inside it. 
I want to merge two types of objects together.
For example : 1-10 stands for froms and
11-20 stands for Tos
So I want to merge Ṭos and froms and instead of showing them 1-20. I want to show 1-11, 2-12 and respectively. 
How can I achieve this in angularJs.

Comment: provide a sample source dataset and result dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use simple javascript to do this.

Iterate halfway through the originalArray using an index variable and push elements from both the ranges at the same time in a new array.

```
var newArray = [];
for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
    newArray.push(originalArray[i]);
    newArray.push(originalArray[i+10]);
}
```

I've assumed 20 as the original array length from your example. You can always use array's length property to calculate required values.